# java architecture - which technology stack and plugins to use for this social networking / video editing site idea?

Tags: java, architecture, social-networking

To be succinct:

This startup is developing a social networking website specifically for video editing. (So, one of the greatest technical challenges is moving around, upload and download, or large files >2Gb). The producer decided to go with Java, and his developers have recommended Liferay as the framework to build it all. Now, when I got on board I advocated using Spring and Grails, but i`m actually not sure which exact technology stack & plugins to use to develop this application. I hope you guy would help me out. The requirements are as follows:

- be able to handle large file upload/download
- social networking: a project has many collaborators, a person works on many projects, a project is owned by a project manager, there are status updates and `like` buttons & commenting for videos and photos.
- messaging: messaging like email, and messaging like chat
- project management (have people and raw video files, eventually end up with a marketable movie)
- some form of version control (but which repository should be use? jackrabbit? svn? filesystem? something custom?)

So you see some problems with this: we're reinventing the wheel (version control, project management, email, social networking). But the question I`m asking here is: what Java technologies should we build this upon? Is Liferay a good choice? What about Spring+Grails? Any other ideas?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Stay away from portlets if possible. I don't know if liferay supports anything else but I have used it as a portal container and was not impressed at all. Just a lot of non-needed complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> messaging: messaging like email, and
>   messaging like chat

I would advice you to use redis because it is lightning fast. [Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) is the most popular redis client for java.

> some form of version control

I would advise you to use [git](http://git-scm.com/) and maybe [github](http://github.com) to host your project. Github will cost you some money, but github is seriously the best.

Comment: Some form of version control for the users, not for developers. For example: a video editing project with 10 collaborators, 100 files, of which 20 files are over 2Gb. They want to keep track of the revisions of their project files. In Java there is jackrabbit, but there is also plain-old SVN (it`d be outside our Java webapp, I set forth the idea that we`d have file and version management completely outside the webapp). Or we can have our own versioning by copying old files to a new location on server`s filesystem and storing a pointer to that old file in a relational database.